# Delphi, TThread.Queue. O que é? Quando deve ser usado?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, thread

Estava vendo esse método que faz uso de thread:

```delphi
procedure TFormClient.QueueLogMsg(const s: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      LogMsg(s)
    end
  );
end;
```

**O que é esse método `TThread.Queue`?**
**Diferentemente da implementação de uma classe herdade de `TThread`, `TThread.Queue` é indicado para quais casos?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```pascal
procedure Queue(AMethod: TThreadMethod); overload;
procedure Queue(AThreadProc: TThreadProcedure); overload;
class procedure Queue(AThread: TThread; AMethod: TThreadMethod); overload;
class procedure Queue(AThread: TThread; AThreadProc: TThreadProcedure); overload;
```

[`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) faz com que a chamada especificada pelo parâmetro `aMethod` seja executado usando o segmento principal(*main thread*), evitando assim conflitos entre múltiplas *threads*. A *thread* atual é passada pelo parâmetro `AThread`.

[`TThread.Queue`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Queue@TThread@TThreadMethod.html) é recomendado utilizar em situações em que você não tem afirmação se o método a ser usado é [*thread-safe*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

A imagem abaixo ilustra como é feito isso.

[image] 
<sub>Crédito da imagem: [*aviyehuda.com*](http://www.aviyehuda.com/)</sub>

[`TThread.Queue`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Queue@TThread@TThreadMethod.html) é comparável ao método [`Synchronize`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Synchronize@TThread@TThreadMethod.html) porém, com uma única **exceção**, em relação a *thread* atual, ao utilizar o método `Synchronize` a *thread* atual é suspensa até que o método seja executado no segmento principal, em contrapartida, ao utilizar `TThread.Queue` a execução da *thread* é permitida a continuar.